# Gettting CORS error on react app vercel deployment backend with render

Tags: reactjs, express, cors, render, vercel

I have hosted my client side (REACT) with vercel and server side (expressjs & mongoose) with Render.
When I run my client side locally everything works fine however it's not working with vercel deployment. Showing CORS Error.
I have enabled cors for all origins. still it is getting the error on vercel deployment.

here's my axios config for frontend

```
const axiosPublic = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
});
```

here's backend code:

```
app.use(cors());
```

Initially I used cors config, which looked like this:

*config file*

```
const allowedOrigins = [
    "https://rey-server.onrender.com",
    "https://reyfurnisher.vercel.app",
    "http://localhost:4000",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://localhost:5000",
];

module.exports = allowedOrigins;
```

*cors options file:*

```
const allowedOrigins = require("./allowedOrigins");

const corsOptions = {
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
        if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback(new Error("Not Allowed by CORS"));
        }
    },
    credentials: true,

    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};

module.exports = corsOptions;
```

*server.js file:*

```
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Screenshot of my network tab.
https://prnt.sc/K760DmXAdmYa

[image: this is from arc browser]

[image: this is from chrome browser]

`It's strange that, when I try to load the page in google chrome the page is empty and nothing loading in the network tab as well. However, in arc, safari and firefox it's showing error in network tabs.`

`response header`
[image: response header]

`request header`
[image: request header]

``

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the preflight request and response.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of my network tab. does that help?

Comment: Please embed the screenshot in the question rather than linking off site.

Comment: I embedded the screenshots but looks like it is not loading properly, at least from my end.if you want you can visit the lightshot url link to check the network tab image.

Comment: Without a screenshot of the preflight request and response, identifying the source of the problem will be difficult...

Comment: I just added 2 more images of request header and repsonse header from netwrok tab. if i am still providing you wrong information, please guide me on preflight request and response.

Comment: What does the CORS error message say? Add it to your question.

Comment: You cannot use the wildcard `*` in responses to credentialed requests. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Comment: thanks all. I was just testing with * wildcard. 
btw, i don't know what was the actual issue. I moved my app from render to railway and everything is working fine. I didn't face any issue. Pretty strange but solved my issue.